# How can I insert data from a connection to other connection?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to insert data from a table which connection is oracle to another table which connection is `mysql`. I use netbeans and `jdbc` driver.
Is it possible? I mean how can I do select data from `A` table (`X` connection) and insert `B` table (`Y` connection)

```
connection X = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host__ + ":" + port__ + servic, props);
connection Y = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
conn.close();
```

Thank you.

Comment: yes, what makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I cant do it. Because there are 2 different jdbc connection.

Comment: At this point you should probably just show us what you've tried, and then paste errors and/or describe the problems you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that copies a database table to another database. 
You just need two connections conf(rom) and cont(o). You will need to modify both getConnection parameters, table names and field types.

```
    // Copy
    Statement stf, stmt;
    Connection conf, cont;
    ResultSet rsf, rs;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conf = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:" + databaseFrom, "user1", "passwd1");
        try {
            stf = conf.createStatement();
            rsf = stf.executeQuery("select * from supplier order by sname");

            // read from rsf write to rs!
            cont = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databaseTo, "user2", "passwd2");
            stmt = cont.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from supplier order by sname");

            while (rsf.next()) {
                rs.moveToInsertRow();

                rs.updateInt(1, rsf.getInt(1));
                rs.updateString(2, rsf.getString(2));
                rs.updateString(3, rsf.getString(3));
                rs.updateString(4, rsf.getString(4));
                rs.updateInt(5, rsf.getInt(5));
                rs.updateString(6, rsf.getString(6));
                rs.updateInt(7, rsf.getInt(7));
                rs.updateDouble(8, rsf.getDouble(8));
                rs.updateString(9, rsf.getString(9));

                rs.insertRow();
            }

        } catch (SQLException s) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "problem creating database " + s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        if (stf != null) {
            try {
                stf.close();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // handle Exception
            }
        }
        if (conf != null) {
            try {
                conf.close();
                cont.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // handle Exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but both connections are mysql? so Connection class is the same but if the connections are different which connection class should I use

Comment: You will need to modify conf, and make it an Oracle connection. Other than that you are ready to go.

Comment: okey I can do the conf and make it oracle connection. and then what should I write when I define connection? I mean connection conf,cont; which type connection is that? I mean it is mixed.

Comment: You are reading conf and writing to cont. Cont stays MySQl, according to what you are asking.

Comment: Can I make the script dynamically. I mean I want to write select * but How can I read data ? I do not want to write column order. Because if a table has 100 column it is a big problem?

Comment: You can make it dynamically if you use metadata in order to find the types of the table attributes. Therefore 100 columns is no big deal...

Comment: how can I do it? can you give me q little sample. Thank you

Comment: Check the Java tutorial for resultSet.getMetaData(). metadata returns the information you need.

Comment: In your code , I insert to table one by one each row. I want to insert all rows at one step. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You could probably avoid programming by saving your oracle data base table to a CSV file and then importing the CSV in mysql. There are also tools that will help you do that. Try github.com/OpenRefine

Answer (score 1):

You can create two classes for different connection:

```
public class OracleConnectionManager {
    public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle","username","password");
        return connection;
    }
}


public class MySqlConnectionManager {
    public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:mysql","username","password");
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Now you can use these classes to get the specific connections and do whatever you want.
You can get the oracle database connection and get the oracle statement > Resultsset, iterate over it 
and insert the data into mysql.

Please let me know in case more information is required.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to ask how can  iterate over it? I mean I execute a query like select * from .. and then I get the data and how can I insert the data to another connection.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Connect to the Oracle database with one data access class
- Connect to the MySQL database with a different data access class
- Read row(s) from a table in the Oracle database
- Perform any column transformations
- Write row(s) to a table in the MySQL database
- Close the database connections

Comment: Thanks for answering. But How can I load from one to other?

Comment: Instantiate the OracleConnection class and instantiate the MySQLConnection class in the ColumnTransformations class.  Then you can reference both connections.  Every bullet point is a separate Java class (except for the close connections).

Comment: what is the 4. step. Icant understand how can I perform column transformations? I mean there is 2 connection which is open. I load data to 1. connection and then how can I insert data to other connection.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a column type in Oracle exists in MySQL. There's no guarantee that a column type in MySQL exists in Oracle.